# Scala, Play Framework Slick issue - could not find implicit value for parameter rconv

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, slick, play-slick

I'm following guidelines of [Slick documentation](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/1.0.1/sql.html) and I don't understand what I'm doing wrong here:

```
package models

import scala.slick.session.Database
import Database.threadLocalSession
import scala.slick.jdbc.{GetResult, StaticQuery => Q}
import javax.sql.DataSource
import Q.interpolation

object Data {

    case class User(user: String, password: String)

    lazy val db = Database.forName("default")

    def result: Option[User] = {
        db.withSession {
            sql"SELECT user, password FROM user WHERE user = 'user' AND password = 'pass'".as[User]
        }
    }

}
```

The line

```
sql"SELECT user, password FROM user WHERE user = 'user' AND password = 'pass'".as[User]
```

is giving me this:

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - could not find implicit value for parameter rconv: scala.slick.jdbc.GetResult[models.Data.User]
    - could not find implicit value for parameter rconv: scala.slick.jdbc.GetResult[models.Data.User]
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Play Framework 2.2.0, Scala 2.10.3, Slick 1.0.1

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to provide the conversion function from result to user. Copied and adapted straight from the [slick home](http://slick.typesafe.com/#tabs-3):

```
implicit val getUserResult = GetResult(r => User(r.<<, r.<<))
```

Or [this section](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/1.0.1/sql.html#query-statements) from the documentation you linked

Comment: But where should this conversion function exist?  within the User class?  Within the function that is performing the query?  somewhere else?  That is the question I never see answered.  Also every time I try this I get "diverging implicit expansion" error

Comment: @EricHartford In my example I've put it inside `Data` object just below `case class User`, don't know if that helps. Also, look up my other questions regarding the same topic - I've got like half a dozen of them solved.

Comment: Doesn't really matter where you put it, as long as it's in scope. In some circumstances Scala automatically imports implicits present in the companion objects, so in the `User` companion object might be a good place.